# Vue.js / How to sort by data using buefy

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use Vue.js and Buefy to construct the front end.

I have a color field with red, black, and orange.

I want to sort the b-table through the color field.

However, the sorting methods I found are ascending and descending. Can I sort by the color of the fields I want?

If possible, please help me.

**component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <b-table 
        :data="users">

        <template slot-scope="props">
            <b-table-column label="id" sortable>
              {{props.row.id}}
            </b-table-column>

            <b-table-column field="content" label="content" sortable>
              {{props.content}}
            </b-table-column>
            <b-table-column field="color" label="color" sortable>
              {{props.color}}
            </b-table-column>
        </template>
      </b-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. paste some code.

Comment: Yes. Code added.
I first tried to sort by user.id. But this also does not work.

Comment: And I ultimately want to sort through the fields user.color (red, black, orange) rather than user.id the way I want. ex) 1. red, 2. orange, 3. black

Answer (score 1):

Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/mazinoukah/7wdje649/3/

All you need to do is add the 'sortable' prop to the b-table-column component.

```js
Vue.use(Buefy.default)

var App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    switchState: true,
    checkboxState: true
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy"></script>
<html>

  <head>
  
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
  
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="app">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-2">
      <section>
 

        <b-table
            :data="[{ id: 44, color: 'red' }, { id: 343, color: 'black' }, { id: 56, color: 'orange' }]"
            :default-sort-direction="defaultSortDirection"
            default-sort="user.first_name"
            aria-next-label="Next page"
            aria-previous-label="Previous page"
            aria-page-label="Page"
            aria-current-label="Current page">

            <template slot-scope="props">
                <b-table-column field="id" label="ID" width="40" sortable numeric>
                    {{ props.row.id }}
                </b-table-column>

                <b-table-column field="color" label="color" sortable>
                    {{ props.row.color }}
                </b-table-column>

               
            </template>
        </b-table>
    </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a method that sorts your `users` object based on one of its keys (color):

```
methods: {
  sortUsers() {
    this.users.sort(function(a, b) {
      var colorA = a.color.toUpperCase();
      var colorB = b.color.toUpperCase();
      return (colorA < colorB) ? -1 : (colorA > colorB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
  },
},
```

Now you can call that method by clicking on a button.